# System.Timers.Timer class execution , accuracy test

Tags: c#, timer

I've write this simple code but the results is unreasonable:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    write w = new write();
}
public class write{
Timer timer = new Timer(100);

public write()
{
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Start();
}
StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("write.txt");
int index = 0;
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    index++;
    if (index>100)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        str.Close();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //do something
        //run simple commands
    }
    str.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
}
```

and the result:

`263
365
479
585
697
803
917
24
132
242
348
462
569
675
787
899
6
113
225
331
443
550
664
770
876
988
95
209
315
427
533
647
754
860
972
78
192
299
405
517
629
736
843
955
61
173
280
394
500
606
718
825
939
45
157
263
377
484
590
702
808
922
29
135
247
353
467
574
686
792
904
11
118
230
336
448
555
669
775
887
993
107
214
320
432
538
652
759
865
977
83
197
304
416
522
634
741
848
960
66`

why it cannot be executed by 100ms step? does really a for with 1000 iteration(without any command) and writing to file is executed about 12ms?(see the last results).

Comment: Your accuracy test makes no sense for me. It depends upon resources availablity.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In brief:** The mean step in time you observe is approx. 109.15 ms. More samples will likely converge to a mean of 109.375 ms. The granularity of the system time may be 15.6250 ms on your system (*Note: This may vary depending on the hard/software platform*). Seven steps of system time progress accumulate to 109.3750 ms. This pretty much tells that you're running on a 15.6250 ms heartbeat platform.

You may improve the accuracy by changing the systems timing behavior. Windows allows you to do this with the [timeBeginPeriod function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:** More details: [Obtaining and Setting Timer Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#define TARGET_PERIOD 1         
TIMECAPS tc;
UINT     wTimerRes;

if (timeGetDevCaps(&tc, sizeof(TIMECAPS)) != TIMERR_NOERROR) 
{
    // Error; application can't continue.
}
// Note: tc.wPeriodMin will be 1 for most platforms, however, the following
// line won't allow anything smaller than 1.

wTimerRes = min(max(tc.wPeriodMin, TARGET_PERIOD), tc.wPeriodMax);
// the smallest permitted period is assigned to wTimerRes.

timeBeginPeriod(wTimerRes); 
// most people just say timeBeginPeriod(1); but that's rude
// this call will set the systems interrupt period to the minimum possible.
```

Running at a smaller interrupt period will force the update of the system time to occurr more often on Windows > XP SP3 (5.1.3). This reduces the granularity of the system time and consequently the granularity of `System.Timers.Timer`. Remember this may not apply to specific platforms operating with Windows XP.

Your're likely to obtain an accuracy of one millisecond. However, there is no guarantee because the scheduling may pause your task for an unspecified amount of time. This can only be overcome by an increased process/thread priority. See the [SetPriorityClass function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the [SetThreadPriority function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Scheduling Priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details about priorities and ways to modify them.

Comment: how musch it can be improved?can I gain about 5 milisecond accuracy?

Comment: @abdolah: with some coding effort easily 5 ms or even less. See the additional information in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Timer class is notoriously inaccurate

Stopwatch is accurate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

But doesn't support scheduling. If you want accurate scheduling you'll have to find something not in the CLR or write your own.